# Refactor ReactiveCrudRepository.deleteAll().block() to non-blocking code

Tags: spring, spring-data, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Could anybody help me to refactor this code in reactive style?

```
userService.deleteAll().then().block();
userService.saveAll(Flux.just(candidate, tech, pm, hr)).then().block();
```

I think this implementation can be simplified by `onNext(…)` of `then(…)` methods.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: use `.subscribe()` instead of `then().block()`;

Comment: @M.Deinum could you describe why?

Comment: Because with `block`there is nothing reactive about your code it becomes blocking...

Comment: But when i call subcribe() there are nothing happens... I saw the example here: https://springframework.guru/spring-data-mongodb-with-reactive-mongodb/

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're looking for

```
    Mono<Void> mono = userService.deleteAll()
            .thenMany(userService.saveAll(Flux.just(candidate, tech, pm, hr)))
            .then();
```

Subscribing to the resulting `Publisher` (which is a `Mono` in this case) is the natural way to initiate execution.

Once you have your reactive sequence set up, it's about time to consider how you want to execute it. Subscribing to the sequence is the natural approach (`.subscribe()`) to initiate execution but that's usually not something you'd do inside your own code, unless you have a very good reason to do so. Depending on the source `Publisher` (which is one of the MongoDB/Couchbase/Cassandra drivers in your case), the subscription initiates a non-blocking process that continues to run after the call to `.subscribe()` is finished. Usually your infrastructure (container) triggers subscription and handles synchronization (via `.subscribe(Subscription)`). In the context of a Spring WebFlux controller your code could look like:

```
@PostMapping("…")
public Mono<Void> save() {

    Mono<Void> mono = userService.deleteAll()
            .thenMany(userService.saveAll(Flux.just(candidate, tech, pm, hr)))
            .then();

    return mono;
}
```

By passing on the `Mono<Void>` as part of the server response, you hand over the reactive sequence for execution. The underlying container subscribes to the `Publisher` and writes an HTTP response as soon as the subscription terminates (that's the synchronization part).

If you want to execute the reactive sequence yourself, then you would need to handle synchronization yourself. `Mono.block()`/`Flux.block()` are handy methods to synchronize calls in isolated environments, but that's again something you shouldn't do except for a very good reason. A very good reason might be that you don't have a surrounding container and the code isn't executed at scale. With blocking calls you lose the benefits that the reactive execution model provides you with because a Thread is blocked until the execution terminates.

A last word on `.deleteAll()`: Sometimes you are required to initialize components or a database state by removing or inserting data. All these initializers happen to be executed within a synchronous API (Spring's `afterPropertiesSet()`, JSR 250's `@PostConstruct`). In that particular context, you'd rather stick to the imperative API because you usually don't want to deal with synchronization yourself.